# IndexOf an associative array in javascript

Tags: javascript, key, associative-array, indexof

can someone tell me please how to get index of an associative array??

for example index of key:".launchPad-plankovy"??

```
        var droppableClasses = [
           {key:".stackDrop-plankovy", value:".card-plankovy"}, 
           {key:".launchPad-plankovy", value:".card-plankovy"}
        ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ES6 you can use [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) like this.

```js
var droppableClasses = [{
  key: ".stackDrop-plankovy",
  value: ".card-plankovy"
}, {
  key: ".launchPad-plankovy",
  value: ".card-plankovy"
}];

var index = droppableClasses.findIndex(function(e) {
  return e.key == '.launchPad-plankovy';
})

console.log(index)
```